# Best practice for having a class served via Ioc and Default instance

Tags: c#, ioc-container

in a WPF I've got a class called UserMessageService that I use to dispatch usermessages. I've created implemented it as a singleton but I want to expose it via IoC as well

```
public class UserMessageService : IUserMessageService
{
    private static UserMessageService userMessageService;
    private static readonly object objLock = new object();
    private readonly IMessageMediator messageMediator;

    private UserMessageService()
    {
        messageMediator = ServiceLocator.Default.ResolveType<IMessageMediator>();
    }

    public static UserMessageService Default
    {
       get
       {
           lock (objLock)
           {
               return userMessageService ?? (userMessageService = new UserMessageService());
           }
           
       }
    }

    public void SendMessage(string message,LogMessageTypeEnum type =LogMessageTypeEnum.Info)
    {
        var userMessage = new UserMessage
        {
             Message = message,
             LogMessageType = type
        };

        messageMediator.SendMessageAsync(userMessage);
    }
}
```

What's the best practice to do so?

## UPDATE #1

I've added this during my registration's code (for other Catel's users)

```
   serviceLocator.RegisterType<IUserMessageService>((x) => UserMessageService.Default);
```

Comment: Use `Lazy<T>` instead of locking. It's threadsafe and much faster.

Comment: Where should I use Lazy?

Comment: `private static Lazy<UserMessageService> userMessageService = new Lazy<UserMessageService>();`

And in getter: `return userMessageService.Value`

And remove the lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a factory method and configure the IoC container to use this factory method for the type `UserMessageService`

**Example**

```
IoCContainer.For<UserMessageService>().Use(() => return UserMessageService.Default);
```

Comment: can you provide a sample?

Comment: what IoC container are you using? maybe I can provide the code you need

Comment: I use Catel's one...don't know if you use/know it...btw you can write me someone else and I take it a sign

Comment: I've added an example, how it could look like. I'll look into Catel now and see if I can provide the correct code

Comment: Sorry, I only found the XML config. Is it possible to configure it in code too?